# Trying to scroll only div, and not whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I tried everything but without success.
Im trying to do that when someone is scrolling the right screen, he will scroll only him and not the whole page. *This is my code:*

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
  <div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<button id="button">
Click me
</button>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="new-content">
<p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.new-content {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: auto;
  background: #f60;
}
.new-content.half,
.content-container.half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('.new-content').toggleClass('half').delay(600).fadeIn(100);
  $('.content-container').toggleClass('half');
});
```

** Note that I knew that if I'll make `height` to be 100vh on `.new content` instead of `auto` it will be fixed, but I don't know exactly the height of this part and therefore I need it to be auto (it will be more than 100vh).*
***Fiddle:*** https://jsfiddle.net/adf4uu31/1/

Comment: How is it that you want it to scroll and still has a dynamic height?

Answer (score 0):

set `content-container` to `position : fixed` and set `new-content` to `float :right` in the css

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't gives me an option to scroll now. And the items that under the 100% screen aren't appear

Comment: Don't forget to run the fiddle script (up left on the page) after making the adjustements I ve suggested....I made the changes on your original fiddle scripts...Make the changed then hit `run` up left then try and see...You'llnotice the orange pane, though the only one moving when scrolling, is behing the grey pane...But that's another problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you do want the right pane to scroll so it doesn't become huge, but since the list may be shorter you don't want to give it a fixed value.
In that case you can use

```
.new-content {
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Well, I wrote in my question......... ** Note that I knew that if I'll make height to be 100vh on .new content instead of auto it will be fixed, but I don't know exactly the height of this part and therefore I need it to be auto (it will be more than 100vh).*

Comment: I thought maybe you meant a fixed height, since you're referencing the height attribute, whereas max-height is not a fixed height but rather a fixed value.
To me it's not really clear what you want to achieve, maybe you could try explaining it a bit more?
Perhaps you might be helped by using flexbox, is that an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Update the `height` in the `.new-content` class to `100vh`. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/adf4uu31/2/

Answer (score 0):

If the height of the container is not fixed, then the div element height increases as its content grows, this will avoid the scroll bar. So, you need to have a fixed height for the interaction with scroll bar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
  $('.new-content').css({'height' : '100vh' }).toggleClass('half').delay(600).fadeIn(100);
  $('.content-container').toggleClass('half');
});
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.content-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  background: #ddd;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow : auto;
}
.new-content {
  display: none;
  overflow: auto;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: auto;
  background: #f60;
}
.new-content.half,
.content-container.half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
  <div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<button id="button">
Click me
</button>
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="new-content">
<p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p>
  </div>
```